# Avoid Cassandra 2.1 Warning trigger directory does not exist

Tags: java, cassandra

Creating a new Cassandra and do a simple insert results in the unexpected warning:

> SharedPool-Worker-1] WARN  o.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities - Trigger directory doesn't exist, please create it and try again.

Checking the source it seams that Cassandra is expecting a trigger directory (default name 'triggers') to exist.

Since I start a fresh Cassandra every time, I would like to know how I can advice Cassandra to create the triggers directory itself. I do not want to artificially fumble with it.

[update] The Cassandra uses the default main method and is started in the user space. Since during the cassandra.yaml definition the directories for cache, data and third one are created I wonder where to specify the trigger directory or how else it is going to be created.

@close screamers
Having an annoying warning in the logs that should not exist after all is what I consider a bug so please allow this question... . (no offense, just plain stackoverflow begging)

Comment: Two questions:  Which OS are you running Cassandra on?  And what user does Cassandra run as?

Comment: This sounds like a permissions problem, check your linux security settings.

Answer (score 4):

As I learned from the code of the FBUtilities.cassandraTriggerDir method, the property "cassandra.triggers_dir" is read before trying the default trigger directory "triggers". By setting the property to the correct directory (after creation) solved the issue.

The main reason for the problem was first, the triggers directory did not exist at all and second the Cassandra directory is not part of the class path. So there was no way Cassandra could not detect the trigger directory correctly.

So to summaries a cassandra.yaml entry is missing for this issue.

PS: Thanks Bryce for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a trigger defined on the table you are inserting into, or in your schema?  Or did you upgrade Cassandra from a pre 2.0 version?

In any case, the `/triggers` directory for 2.1 depends on your install type.

- For a tarball install, it should be: `{install_location}/conf/triggers`
- For a packaged install, it should be: `/etc/cassandra/triggers`

Comment: I just erase the complete directory of Cassandra, create a cassandra.yaml out of a configuration class I wrote and start Cassandra. So its a complete fresh install and Cassandra is just initialized with the proper cassandra.config property set to the file. So I wonder if I miss a simple setting I have to turn on. The warning is issued on insert and I have no triggers specified.

Comment: @MartinKersten I couldn't find anything specific to trigger use/creation in my 2.1.4 `cassandra.yaml` file.  But I can tell you that whichever directory your `cassandra.yaml` lives in, is the same directory where you need a `triggers` directory.  Try creating it and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Am I really supposed to create the triggers directory myself?

Comment: @MartinKersten if you're going to be blowing away the entire Cassandra dir and re-creating everything from your own custom app, then "yes."

Comment: Solved the issue and find the final reason. The Cassandra directory is ment to be on the classpath which it is not in my case. The cassandra.yaml surely misses a property for the trigger directory.